# DateDiff with french format

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm struggling with a problem about Dates manipulation.

**Background :**

Access 2013 - Classic Stock Table (id, name_item, record_date)

Currently working on SearchForm.
Have to finish the last filter (dates) - Others filters work.

```
I designed a ComboBox to filter "< 7 days", "< 30 days",...
```

**PBM :** 
Date format is d/m/y (french format)

Operator < seems to compare with m/d/y even my date are defined in d/m/y.
I verified both Type in Table and Date(), they're set in d/m/y

**CODE :**

```
If InputDate.Value = "La semaine derniere" Then
        strfilter = strfilter & "([Record_date] > #" & DateAdd("d", -7, Date) & "#)"
        Debug.Print Month(DateAdd("d", -7, Date)) & " " & strfilter
```

**Output :**

```
 9 ([Record_date] > #03/09/2015#)
```

I tried also `strfilter = strfilter & "(Datediff('d', date(), [Record_date]) < 7)"`

No difference :'(.

Any idea how I can go through this problem please.

Falt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the date value as a string expression formatted to yyyy/mm/dd:

```
strfilter = strfilter & "([Record_date] > #" & Format(DateAdd("d", -7, Date), "yyyy\/mm\/dd" & "#)"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Correct me if i'm wrong but the > operator on Date compare : any format < yyyy/mm/dd (I'm asking because my Date format on my table is dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: The date format for the field is for display only, it doesn't affect the actual date value.